# Confusion about inverse modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCkl7.png)

The s just simply pops into inverse and i dont even know why. Tried to find some youtube and it makes me confuse even more.

Answer (score 0):

They found $$s=-1839$$

Apparently they like tohave a positive value for $s$ and since the calculations are mod $(5800)$ they simply added $5800$ to $-1839$ and we have $$5800-1839 =3961$$

The inverse module in this case is just shifting your negative remainder to get  a positive remainder.